# how to use Shoulda to test to controller and new AR creation in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automated-tests, shoulda

I am new to using Shoulda and don't know where to begin.

One of the things I want to be able to test is when I create a new record for a given Model, the controller is supposed to then create new records for another model that is related.

How do I make this in Shoulda?

Here is what happens when I create a new record for Email:

```
  def create
 29     @campaign = Campaign.find(params[:campaign_id])
 30     @email = @campaign.emails.build(params[:email])
 31     if @email.save
 32       @email.new_todos # create todos across all contacts for this asset
 33       flash[:notice] = "Successfully created email."
 34       #redirect_to campaign_url(@campaign)
 35       redirect_to :back
 36     else
 37       render :action => 'new'
 38     end
 39   end
```

'@email.new_todos" creates new records for model Todo, which is an extension added across all the models, such as Email:

```
  def create
 29     @campaign = Campaign.find(params[:campaign_id])
 30     @email = @campaign.emails.build(params[:email])
 31     if @email.save
 32       @email.new_todos # create todos across all contacts for this asset
 33       flash[:notice] = "Successfully created email."
 34       #redirect_to campaign_url(@campaign)
 35       redirect_to :back
 36     else
 37       render :action => 'new'
 38     end
 39   end
```

I would like to slowly start incorporating tests and am picking key types of behavior where it seems likely to break down to learn how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is better suited to a unit test. Although you're triggering the action in a controller, the logic is in the model.

Shoulda adds convenience features to `Test::Unit`. Things like contexts and matchers.

I'd test this like so:

```
context '.new_todos' do
  setup do
    @campaign = Campaign.create(:name => 'My Campaign')
    @email = @campaign.emails.build(:subject => 'Test Campaign Email')
    @email.save
    @email.new_todos
  end

  should 'generate todos for all contacts' do
    assert @email.todos.count > 0
  end
end
```

Obviously the sample attributes would need to change and you'll want to ensure you're getting the desired result (I guessed and used `@email.todos`), but it's a start. I'll be happy to update if you can try that out and see what happens.

To test this in the controller, you'll want a functional or integration test. Functional tests are pretty easy with shoulda, too. That would look something like this:

```
context 'POST to :create' do
  setup do
    @campaign = Campaign.create(:name => 'My Campaign')
    @email = 'test@test.com' # or whatever data you're expecting
    post :create, :campaign_id => @campaign.id, :email => @email
  end

  should respond_with(:redirect)
  should redirect_to('/some/path')
end
```

That's a start. Good luck!

Comment: I see...how can I validate the data for the newly created Todo?  It should contain, for example, contact_id, an email_id, etcetera...thanks....

Comment: Are you requiring those fields on the model (i.e. `validates_presence_of :contact_id`)? If so, in your unit test you can add `should validate_presence_of(:contact_id)`.

Comment: I see...so basically put everything in the tests in unit, but use the shoulda helpers...would it go into one of the existing files?  Those all seemed for a specific model.

Comment: thanks I think this set me in the right direction for now....may ask more questions later, though :)

Comment: hhi, any suggestions for more information, I am learning alot from this post -- I haven't seen anything online that give what you give so thank you.